# SAP ABAP loop within loop to 7.40 syntax

Tags: abap

Is there any better way of doing this using 7.40 syntax? I cannot use the READ statement since I am using range table.

```
lr_vstel = VALUE #( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ'
                  ( low = '5161' ) ( low = '5361' ) ).
lr_lgort = VALUE #( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ'
                  ( low = '4004' ) ( low = '9013' )
                  ( low = '9014' ) ).

LOOP AT xvbap(] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL (<lfs_vbap>)
  WHERE
        werks = '5161'
    AND vstel IN Ir_vstel
    AND lgort NOT IN lr_lgort.

  LOOP AT xlips[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_lips>)
    WHERE
          posnr = <lfs_vbap>-posnr
      AND vtweg = '20'
      AND lgort NOT IN lr_lgort.

    MESSAGE |Storage location { <lfs_lips>-lgort } is not allowed|
       TYPE 'E'.
    EXIT.

  ENDLOOP.

ENDLOOP.
```

I wanted to avoid the loop within a loop using 7.40 syntax.

Comment: Please "DO NOT post images of code". For more information about how to ask a question, please [read Stack Overflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially explain what you tried ("Search, and research...and keep track of what you find").

Comment: This question should be posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It does not belong to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jagger when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context, and there is no indication that the code belongs to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do it, yes, but to be honest, your solution looks acceptable.

If you want to get other suggestions, you should be more precise in what exactly you want to improve: readability? performance? flexibility in the selection criteria?

You should then also provide sample data and define the side conditions better, for example whether your ranges also need to cover more complex cases, such as excluding entries, or admitting real ranges with low and high end, and whether it would be acceptable to modify the content of the internal tables.